# I need the Values of a picklist in a LWC and not the API Name with JS

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, picklist

as with all my posts I hope you are well. I have the following doubt:

I am working with lwc and I need to have the description of a picklist when executing the onchange event.
This is my code:

LWC:

```
<div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
  <lightning-input-field field-name="BE_LEG_TipoBien__c" data-name="tipoBien" onchange={handleChangeTipoBien}>
  </lightning-input-field>
</div>
```

JS:

```
handleChangeTipoBien(event) {
    let tipoBien = event.target.value;        
    const selectedValue = event.detail.value;
    console.log(event)
    console.log('Selected Value:', selectedValue);
    console.log(tipoBien);
}
```

the problem that when I use event.detail.value; and event.target.value; it brings me the API Name and I need the Values.

Thank you very much for your time.